# What should our chat room's name be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Right now the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16046/moderators) is just called "Moderators". Can we come up with something a little more clever than that?

Comment: Anything but "Diamonds are forever"

Comment: @Oded - though it would be fun to have an outgoing mod set the chat name to that and then have their jewelry removed.

Comment: How about "Troll Here... If You Dare"? (No, not seriously)

Answer (score 26):

Proposed Name: The Ban Hammer.

Comment: Ding ding ding, we have a winner!

Comment: When this site comes out of beta (which I'm sure it will), I want the official site design to incorporate a ban hammer as well.

Comment: perhaps we should go so far as to request banhammer.se.com

Comment: One time in Ban Camp...

Answer (score 7):

Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Comment: AKA - Who watches the watchers?

Comment: Quid quid latine dictum sit, altum videtur!

Comment: Moderator mods.

Answer (score 2):

### The mod hole

As long as the site is called “moderators”, this name fits.

If the site is renamed to “Community”, we could rename the chatroom to

### The comm center

Answer (score 1):

"The Round Table" (as in King Arthur's Court)

Answer (score 0):

Fight the System! call it:

The Free For all

Comment: Chat owner for everyone on the way in the door?

Comment: @AJHenderson We talked about this ...

Answer (score -2):

"The [Janitors'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) Closet"

Answer (score -2):

The Ban, the Hammer, and the Mod